# Visual Studio 2012 Strange Signal Icon

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, icons, resharper, resharper-7.1

I have a class in a VS 2012 project whose signal icon is a black diamond (image below).

[image: Unknown Signal Icon - Black Diamond]

I am not familiar with this icon and it is not listed in the [VS 2012 Class View and Object Browser Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on msdn.  Anyone have an idea what this icon means?

I was initially having some problems with the class resolving incorrectly and giving a build error that I have resolved...I initially assumed this was some kind of error signal, however the icon stayed after I got a successful build of the project.

I am also using JetBrains ReSharper 7.1 C# Edition Build 7.1.25.234 on 2012-11-14T00:34:00, but I can't find any injected icons on their website either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon with the black diamond means that this is a *static* class (the following screen shows the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`).

Btw, ... the icon with the "A" means that this is an *abstract* class.

[image: Enumerable code completion (IntelliSense)]